# NextJS Images are not rendered on Vercel

Tags: next.js, vercel, nextjs-image

I have a small issue on my project right now. I try to deploy on Vercel my Next.Js project.
I rendered some images from the public folder, but those images that render perfectly on test does not render when deploy on Vercel.

I'm using the **App Router**. I first try to create a folder inside my **src/images** but the deployement said :
`Module not found: Can't resolve './images/thumbnail/Popup.png'`

Then I searched online and I saw that the best way was to use the **public folder**. I created a 'Thumbnail' folder inside my public folder and the deployement was succesfull but the images never rendered.

[image: How it should be]

This is what I have on test.

But deploy I get this :

[image: How it is]

On my page I use the Next/image that I import.

And a Image looks like this :

```
<Image
            src={"/thumbnail/ProductCard.png"}
            alt="Product Card"
            width={500}
            height={500}
          />
```

I don't know why the images does not render.

Nothing really work. I'm kinda lost right now and I don't know where I did something wrong

This is the repo :

https://github.com/Molikuc/frontend_ideas

Thanks in advance. Have a great day.

I try multiple things like importing the photo with : import image from '/thumbnail.ProductCard.png

I try creating a static/image folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you are developing on Windows. The reason is because if you check your GitHub repo, you shall the files as `public/thumbnail/ProductCard.PNG`. Notice the `.PNG` extension.

On Windows, they work perfectly, because Windows treat both `.PNG` and `.png` extensions as same.

But Vercel is running on a Unix based system, and treats these extensions as differently. Hence it's trying to look for `public/thumbnail/ProductCard.png`, since thats what you pass to `<Image>` component.

```
<Image
    src={"/thumbnail/ProductCard.png"}
    alt="Product Card"
    width={500}
    height={500}
/>
```

Which it won't find. Hence why your images are not rendered on Vercel.

---

So to solve it, you can either:

1. Rename your images in `public` directory to use `.png` extension
2. Update the `src` in `<Image>` component to use `.PNG` extension

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't know that. That solved it.